# How to type an input function as a type guard?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, guard-clause

How can I generalize a function mapping an array of T1 to a array containing only T2 where T2 is a subtype of T1?

```
function filterJustStrings(arr: (string| number)[]) {
  return arr.filter((i) => typeof i === 'string') as string[];
}
```

Given predicate functions which are defined as type guards

```
function isNumber(i: any) : i is number {
  return typeof i === 'number';
}

function isString(i: any) : i is string{
  return typeof i === 'string';
}
```

I would like to improve the typing of this function:

```
function filterJustT<TWide extends T, T>(predicate: (i: TWide) => boolean): (arr: TWide[]) => T[] {
  return (arr: TWide[]) => arr.filter((i) => predicate(i)) as T[];
}
```

So that the return type is inferred using the guard type

```
const filterJustStrings2 = filterJustT(isString);
const filterJustStrings3 = filterJustT(isNumber);
```

The code above infers the expected input correctly based on the input of the predicate, but the return type is unknown[]

Is there a way to extract the guard type narrowing?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function filterJustT<T>(predicate: (i: any) => boolean): (arr: any[]) => T[] {
  return (arr: any[]) => arr.filter((i) => predicate(i)) as T[];
}

const filterJustStrings2 = filterJustT<string>(test);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMGAbKBTATgKRAZygGUosYwBzfACgEMssAuRawsygH0TBAFsAjbAEoA2gF0hiAN4BYAFCJEWDFBBYk9LADoU6bNWoxJAXgB8iKAE8ADhjjBEMRMZeIA5G3IU3k2vkSelOIA3PIAvvLyoJCwCI74AHJ8gliGzLRglpLMTjD%20PALY0vKKyqrqFjZ2Dk4uxu4FKW6hchFyUeDQ8Eh5JOwUaYgZWYg58QGkXrIKSipqSFa29o7Orh6TlM3hkXLRXXGYhIPDQsz8cHCoGBnFM2XzyLSo%20BgtbR0x3chomLgEUAAVAA8ANM1GsygAJjAILRMMxjpkTOZzpdrmBTixNOlMuJkYgAeJbqU5hU6AwcZY8c5zJodD99IZ8RCMNDYZgmb5-ISxG8dhAEIRvno-oQ%20l58AAmZzC354QjAwIUMGHKBCFoCsBC3Ry-7iyj4ADMMp12HlgMMiWSwha8k12oZouIGyoABYTY7zYqXSqMIR1QB6AOAXg3AER7QA)